# Dynamically alter the height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I put UITableViewCell by xib file.
And, I want to change the height of Cell depending on the height of UITextView put in Cell.

I found an online article.
I think that it went according to this article.
But TableViewCell does not change depending on the height of TextView.
Please tell me where is wrong.

I will detail in detail what I did below.

1. I created UITableView and Cell (Xib) as shown below.

TableView.swift

```
import UIKit

class TableView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var newImage: UIImageView!
    //etc...

    class func instance() -> TableView {
        return UINib(nibName: "TableView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! TableView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = newTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCellTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }


}
```

Cell.swift

```
import UIKit

class NewCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let bottomBorder = CALayer()
    let vArchColor   = archColor()

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        bottomBorder.frame           = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.frame.size.height - 1.0, width: self.frame.width*2, height: 1.0)
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = vArchColor.black01.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        print("Selected")
    }

}
```

2. I  set several necessary values in UITableView.

   // in TableView.swift
   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
       newTableView.beginUpdates()
       newTableView.endUpdates()
   }

   // in TableView.swift
   func initSomething(){
       newTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       newTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10000
   }
3. I  used Storyboard in Cell (XibFile) and set constraints.
   Of course, I also unchecked scrollenabled.
   Image of Cell.xib
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've provided an implementation for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` which will override on a per row basis any constant value you have set in `tableView.rowHeight = ...`. Remove this method from your TableViewController and you should be golden, provided the constraints of your text view aren't ambiguous. Make sure it's pinned on all four sides **and** has a height constraint.

Comment: Thanks to you, my two - day battle closed.
I solved this by deleting this code. "func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)"